# Android NDK Linking shared library unsatisfied Linker Error

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

i have a problem,

Below is the Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
INITIAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpegbuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libffmpeg.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


LOCAL_PATH := $(INITIAL_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE    := main_module
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm  # remove this if you want thumb mode
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ffmpegbuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

It creates the two shared_libraries as expected. i see those two libraries inside `libs/armeabi` folder
When i run the application, Unsatisfied Linker error occurs as

```
01-06 20:21:38.281: E/AndroidRuntime(435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 20:21:38.281: E/AndroidRuntime(435): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1962]:    32 could not load needed library 'libffmpeg.so' for 'libmain_module.so' (load_library[1104]: Library 'libffmpeg.so' not found)
01-06 20:21:38.281: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:434)
01-06 20:21:38.281: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
```

What could be the problem, also though i defined `LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpegbuilt`, why the prebuilt library's module name is not changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the second question. No, the name of `LOCAL_MODULE` for prebuilt libraries does not change the name of the file. This is how it was designed. Yes, this name has much more significant effect on *built* static and shared libraries. But rebuilt ones don't follow the same pattern.

Now to your first question. Android does not look for dynamic dependencies in the local app's **lib** directory. There are some technical reasons, and even some workarounds. But normally, we simply [loadLibrary](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) the local shared libraries in Java, keeping the correct order, so that external dependencies be resolved at every step.

In your case, this discussion resolves into

```
System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
System.loadLibrary("main_module");
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, for the 2nd question!.

Comment: I tries your suggestion, but still same case!!

Comment: Thanks alex, it worked, actually the order of loading library is matters! I tried first loading main_module then ffmpeg, but as you stated, the dependancy should be first added!! I got it

Answer (score 0):

If the ndk build is creating the .so files but unsatisfied Linker error is thrown at runtime. Please check the build.gradle file.

Build.gradle should contain following lines to follow the build steps and refer to shared libraries.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path file('src/main/jni/Android.mk')
    }
}
```

This info can also be added from UI by providing the path of Android.mk file.
Native code an be compiled with either cMake file or Android.mk file.

Follow link -
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds